# caught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')

Tags: javascript, html

Guys my javascript is having an error. It would say caught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick') at SignUp.js:4:43

```html
<HTML>
<body>
<div class="input-box">
   <span class="details">Full Name</span>
   <input id="full_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
</div> 
<div class="button" id="button">
    <button id="button">Submit</button>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function()
{
    var FullName = document.getElementById("full_name").value;
    console.log(FullName);
}
</script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

I'm tring to make a Sign UP form using HTML, CSS, JS

Comment: Your code doesn't reproduce the problem. Please post a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML code, you have two elements with the same ID: "button." IDs should be unique within an HTML document. Having duplicate IDs can lead to unexpected behavior and issues when accessing elements using JavaScript.

To resolve the error, you need to modify your HTML code to ensure unique IDs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="input-box">
   <span class="details">Full Name</span>
   <input id="full_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
</div> 
<div class="button" id="buttonDiv">
    <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("submitButton").onclick = function()
{
    var FullName = document.getElementById("full_name").value;
    console.log(FullName);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```